# Understand the weak comparison function

Tags: http, etag, http-caching, if-none-match

[HTTP 1.1 defines a weak comparison function](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html#sec13.3.3) for cache validators:

> in order to be considered equal,
>           both validators MUST be identical in every way, but **either** or
>           both of them MAY be tagged as "weak" without affecting the
>           result.

I understand that following statement (for two ETags) is true:

```
W/"Foo" = "Foo"
```

Now I'm wondering what real world use case might exist where a server compares a weak ETag against a strong one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are cases where servers first assign a weak etag, and later on promote it to a strong etag (by removing the "W/" prefix). An example is Apache moddav (or is it plain httpd?), when configured to create entity tags based on the filesystem timestamp of the file being served.